# How Do I Write Two Methods In The Same Line

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I have 3 arrays. One for the Item Number, One for Item Description and One for Price.

I want to be able to create a "table" out of it so it reads as:

```
Item Number:    Description:    Price:
   50              Water          $50
   752             Carrots        $.60
   67              Ice             $9
```

and etc. I tried creating methods using a foreach statement and then calling the methods. It works however it doesn't print side by side. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is the code
 `

```
using static System.Console;
class FoodOrder
{
         static void Main()
        {
        //Variables used in the method
        const int MENU_ASTERIKS = 42;
        string description = "Description", itemNumber = "Item number", price = "Price";
        string[] itemDescription = { "Cheese Frise", "Corn Dogs", "Cheeseburger", "Hamburger", "Fries", "Fountain Drink", "Philly Cheese Steak", "Tacos" };
        int[] itemNumList = { 20, 23, 25, 31, 35, 38, 39, 34, };
        double[] itemPrice = { 2.95, 1.95, 2.25, 3.10, 4.50, 3.65, 5.00, 2.75};
        Write("\t");
        for (int x = 0; x < MENU_ASTERIKS; ++x) //Creates a top border for the menu with the prices and is the start of the menu 
            Write("*");
        WriteLine(" ");
        Write("\t   {0}\t{1}\t{2}", itemNumber, description, price);
        DisplayItemNum(itemNumList); DisplayDescriptions(itemDescription);
    }
        //Method to dispay item number
        private static void DisplayItemNum( params int[] itemNums)
        {
        WriteLine("\n");
        foreach (int number in itemNums)
            WriteLine("\t        {0} ", number);
        }
        //Method to Display item Number
        private static void DisplayDescriptions(params string[] desc)
        {
        WriteLine("\n");
        foreach (string objects in desc)
            WriteLine("\t\t\t{0}", objects);


        }

}
```

`

[image: source code]

[image: output of source file]

Comment: Please enter your code instead of the image. It will be easier to read

Comment: @D.J. I tried this but this just writes the objects in the array on the same line

Answer (score 3):

Right now you're looping 3 times, for all the lists. Then you call `Console.WriteLine` which adds a newline character to the end of your output, so it displays on next line.

What you istead want to do is call `Console.Write` which does not add the newline character. There are also better ways to do this. Instead of keeping 3 seperate lists, you could also bundle your information in a class and create a list of that:

```
public class MyTableRow
{
   public int Number {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}
   public float Price {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can create a new object of this class, fill that with your data and `.Add()` that to a list in you `Main`, e.g. `var MyTableRows = new List<MyTableRow>();` then `MyTableRows.Add(new TableRow{ Number = 1, Description = "REE", Price = 1.0f});`

You can then loop that list and display the output.

Comment: @Sommment ohkay so I am really new to c#  and just got to the methods in my class so I kind of understand this, so I am going to try it. If you have time would you be able to write a short description of what each action does? so I can learn it better instead of copying and pasting variables?

Comment: @SpacedOutKID hi, well these are really the basics of programming in general so i would suggest you look up some tutorials instead. Also read through all features of the c# language online https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/getting-started/introduction-to-the-csharp-language-and-the-net-framework don't try to understand everything at once, it won't work. First read it all, get a overview in your mind and then get a general idea of what you're doing and then google the bits and pieces together. Thats how i learned, and still learn as a proffesional developer.

Comment: Proffesional as in the sense that i use programming in a proffesional capability, and not like i'm a pro in any way ;)